# swap dimensions of 4-D image array

Tags: image, matlab, permutation

I have a 4-D array of images of shape `[32 32 3 1000]`. In Matlab, how can I change this so that the image number (1000) is the first index instead of the last, i.e. shape `[1000 32 32 3]`?

I tried `A = permute(A, [1000 32 32 3]);`, but it says:

> Error using permute ORDER contains an invalid permutation index.

Comment: You want the 1000th dimension in the first place, the 32th dimension in the second place, the 32th dimension again, in the 3rd place and the 3rd dimension in the 4th place. This may work for a 1000-D matrix (not a 4-D matrix), if it fits in memory. Or did you not read the documentation ;)

Comment: Sorry edited to be 1000

Comment: Read again. The documentation too ;)

Comment: Ahhh okay I get it, thanks!